# iterating over array and creating new dictionary

Tags: python

i have got an array that i have got from vcenter using python pyVmomi module

the array name is clustr_group_info ,you as seen below

```
>>> type(clustr_group_info)
<class 'pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.vim.cluster.GroupInfo[]'>
```

the content of the array look as below:

```
print(clustr_group_info)
(vim.cluster.GroupInfo) [
(vim.cluster.VmGroup) {
  dynamicType = <unset>,
  dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
  name = 'group1',
  userCreated = <unset>,
  uniqueID = <unset>,
  vm = (vim.VirtualMachine) []
},
(vim.cluster.HostGroup) {
  dynamicType = <unset>,
  dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
  name = 'group2',
  userCreated = <unset>,
  uniqueID = <unset>,
  host = (vim.HostSystem) [
     'vim.HostSystem:host-631607',
     'vim.HostSystem:host-631791'
  ]
},
```

i need to create a new dictionary for each iteration with "name" as key and
"host" as a value 
i was not able to iterate over the array  , in the regular way

```
>>> for i in clustr_group_info[0]:
...     print(i)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'vim.cluster.VmGroup' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the whole array, not the first item in it `[0]`. Like so:

```
for i in clustr_group_info:
    print(i.['name']) # If it's a dictionary
    print(i.name) # If it's an object of a class
```

Comment: i am getting  the values show above if i am iterating over "clustr_group_info"  from each dictionary in the array ,i need to create new dictionary ,with name as key and host as value

Comment: it's not clear which datatype `clustr_group_info`'s children are, so I updated the answer to include both cases.